# Resizing image for classification

Tags: python, raster, classification, image

I want to perform supervised classification in Python and in order to perform that I need to have a training sample raster and satellite image. My problem is the training sample raster file has a smaller size (rows X columns) as compared to my satellite image. I have tried to enlarge my training sample size image using PIL but that does not store geo-transformation and other coordinate related information. Is there any other library which performs resizing-increasing the image size to  our original satellite image. Here is the code that I have tried-

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/your image path/alltraining.tiff')
new_width  = 4125
new_height = 6044
img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('output image name.tiff')
```

[image]

satellite image of size- 4125X6144

[image]

Training sample of size- 4002X5894

If I try to perform classification with these rasters I get an error of dimensions does not match